# Spectrum of momentum operator of quantum physics

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

I am stuck with the following problem:

Given the momentum operator of quantum mechanics $Af = - if'$ where the domain $D(A)$ consists of functions $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ that are absolutely continuous and such that $f' \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

(i) Prove that $A$ has no eigenvalues.

(ii) Prove that the continuous spectrum of $A$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

We have already shown in class that $A$ is self-adjoint.

For (i) I would use the equation for eigenvalues $Af = \lambda f$ and then show that this cannot hold. But I came up with a solution which shouldn't be the case.

For (ii) we have to construct a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\geq1}$ in $D(A)$ with $||f_n||=1$ and $||(A-\lambda I)f_n|| \to 0$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, but I have problems finding this sequence.

I would be grateful for any input.

Comment: Hints:
1) Are you sure your solutions are in $L^2$?
2) But perhaps you can find a sequence converging to the above solutions ;)

Comment: Probably the easiest way to do this is to Fourier transform the operator. The spectrum and eigenvalues of a multiplication operator are very easy to determine.

Comment: @LL3.14 thank you for your input! I managed to prove (i) but I haven't been able to construct a sequence that converges to $e^{i \lambda x}$ in $L^2$. Could you give me any more ideas? Thank you very much in advance!